# Why Heroku GitHub deploy is failing

Tags: java, maven, heroku, github, tomcat8

I am working a Java REST api for a hobby project and I am using Heroku as my deployment platform. I managed to deploy the application using 
    `heroku-maven-plugin`.

Then I integrated my GitHub repo with heroku app and tried to deploy from master branch. But then it fails with the following message

> Failed to detect set buildpack https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/java.tgz
>
> More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
>
> !Push failed

Can you please explain how to fix this?

**Update** :

I have tried setting the buildpack to `heroku/java` from both dashboard and the heroku CLI tool. But still the problem remains.

GitHub : [online-activity-diary-api](https://github.com/isurunix/online-activity-diary-api)

Comment: What version of the heroku-maven-plugin? Can you share your `pom.xml`?

Comment: nevermind. i see the code. what command are you using to deploy? `mvn heroku:deploy`?

Comment: @codefinger. `mvn heroku:deploy` works perfect. I am having a problem when try to deploy from heroku dashboard

Answer (score 0):

The Heroku Maven plugin and Github deployment to the same app are not compatible. They use different buildpacks that do different work. You'll first need to make sure your deploying to different apps with these two mechanisms.

When you deploy with Github sync, you'll need to make sure your buildpack is configured to `heroku/java` in the dashboard. Then make sure your application has a `pom.xml` checked into Git.

Comment: I have configured the buildpack as `heroku/java` in the dashboard. But still I am getting the same error.